# what does config.py when imported to other python files?

Tags: python

I'm reading other's code, and there is a config.py file. When it gets imported to other files, it would run first. What is the function of this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no different from any other python source file. There is NO magic.

When you import a python source file, you make available all the contents of the imported file to the code in the file that is doing the import.

Please read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html